# Specifying external log4j properties file for one application in JBOSS container

Tags: spring, logging, jboss, log4j, classloader

I've been around the houses with this so would appreciate some help. I am trying to get my application, deployed as an ear in JBoss, to use a `log4j.properties` file that sits outside the application. There are other applications deployed in the same JBoss container and I don't want to effect them. I have tried a number of approaches but can't quite get it to work. Any advice welcome.

Here are some of the things that I have tried that haven't worked:

1. Added log4j.properties to JBoss classpath. Didn't work because of conflict with JBoss log4j, detailed [here](http://majikshoe.blogspot.ie/2010/01/log4j-and-jboss.html).
2. Specified `log4j.properties` file location on startup by adding `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:\.....\log4j.properties` to JBoss startup script. This was unsuccessful as it picked up log statements from the other applications in the container.
3. Tried specifying `log4j.properties` location in `web.xml` of WAR file in EAR file but I got the same error detailed in the link in step 1 above.

Any ideas on how to get this working? JBoss EAP 5.1, Spring 3.1.1, log4j 1.2.16.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it. In web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.applicationName.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
     <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
     <param-value>10000</param-value>
</context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Note the use of a file name other than log4j.properties. Don't know if this will alleviate your conflict but might. Of course, the problem with this config is that you get no logs for the first 10 seconds of start-up. That might be important.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out why I don't get my startup sequence. The above needs to come before the context load listener in web.xml and 10 seconds is to long. I changed it to 1 second, now it seems to work really well.